# Copy Adjacent Cells alongside Duplicate Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a very large Google Sheet spreadsheet that I need help with.

I have a long list of Network Switches that are very often repeated that I am trying to automatically copy the associated SKU into a separate adjacent cell.

My goal was, once the SKU is added the first time, whenever the same switch is added again, it will autopopulate with the same SKU.

[image: Here is a brief image of the spreadsheet]

For instance, C2461:C2463 are repeated, and once K2461 is populated, would like K2462 & K2463 to follow suit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am willing to share a solution with you if you will share a link to a *copy* of your spreadsheet. You can completely delete all column data other than Col C and Col K if you like, since those are all I need. This would be a formula solution, not a script solution.

Comment: Of course!

Here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BtsmfeNug8siRtLvgmsNo71sLh6t5u2lQ266y65yVW0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet is "View only," so I can't yet implement the solution I have in mind. Please change the link's Share settings to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this formula on Column L (col L will serve as a helper column):

```
=iferror(arrayformula(VLOOKUP(C2:C,C2:K,9,False)),"")
```

For now I can't seem to fit the formula without the use of a helper column (so I created a separate sheet for now that will serve as a database for the `VLOOKUP` formula) but this should get you started.

**Sample using a helper spreadsheet (Database):**

```
=iferror(arrayformula(VLOOKUP(Database!A2:A,Database!A2:B,2,False)),"")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This completely did the trick!  Thank you so much for the help!